# Multiple source files for grouping

Tags: vb.net

Is using multiple source files possible in VB.net in a similar way to how it is implemented in C++ with `#include` ? I can't seem to find any information on this anywhere, so I'm starting to think that it isn't easily used, or is non-existent.

Comment: search for ascx these are user controls... basically portions of code and markup that can be 'included' into any page. You can even include it in several times on a page if necessary.

Comment: The OP made absolutely no mention of a web application.  `#include` applies to source code, not ASP/markup.
The answer to the question is no, it is dissimilar.  The best way to re-use code is to create a DLL or use a class (or even module) that you keep in a common folder and copy into all your projects.  You can even do that with a linked file so that you don't have to keep updating it manually.  I would recommend the DLL method though.

Comment: @Grim Thank you very much, a little more work than I would like to implement it, but very useful to know, thank you.